# Where is this mysterious Scala object coming from?

Tags: scala, dropwizard, metrics

**Please note:** Although this question has to do with the popular [Dropwizard Metrics](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.2.3/) library and its Scala API analog, [Metrics Scala](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala), this is -- at its core -- strictly a Scala question. As such, I believe any knowledgeable Scala dev can answer this!

---

I am fairly new to Scala and am trying to build a simple app that will leverage this Metrics-Scala library (which again is the Scala API for DW Metrics). I found a very useful GitHub project showing how to setup Metrics-Scala in the real world, and the source file I'm referencing below [can be found here](https://github.com/oschrenk/scala-metrics/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/elmar/metrics/Metrics.scala).

I cut and diced that source file into a much smaller, simpler version to illustrate my question:

```
object Metrics extends App {
  val metricRegistry = new com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry()
  val healthCheckRegistry = new com.codahale.metrics.health.HealthCheckRegistry()

  ConsoleReporter.forRegistry(metricRegistry)
    .convertRatesTo(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .convertDurationsTo(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .build().start(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

  run()

  while(true){}

  def run() {
    new TimerExample().longRunningInstrumentedMethod()

    spawn {
      val gaugeExample = new RandomNumberGaugeExample()

      while (true) {
        Thread.sleep(500)
        gaugeExample.fetchingRandomNumber()
      }
    }
  }
}

trait Instrumented extends InstrumentedBuilder {
  val metricRegistry = Metrics.metricRegistry
}

class RandomNumberGaugeExample() extends Instrumented {
  def fetchingRandomNumber(): Int = {
    metrics.gauge("random-number") {
      Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 1000)
    }.value
  }
}
```

My concerns are with this mysterious `metrics` object and its usage.

I understand that `RandomNumberGaugeExample` inherits a `metricsRegistry` instance because it extends `Instrumented`. But I'm not seeing where that `metrics` instance is defined, what type it is, and how `RandomNumberGaugeExample` gets asscess to it. Wouldn't `RandomNumberGaugeExample` just have access to a `metricsRegistry`?!

Also what is this devilry:

```
metrics.gauge("random-number") {
  Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 1000)
}.value
```

How does `metrics.guage` return an integral value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Instrumented` extends [`InstrumentedBuilder`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/InstrumentedBuilder.scala), which is where we find `metrics`. `metrics` is a [`MetricsBuilder`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/MetricBuilder.scala).

As for `metrics.gauge`, let's look at the [`gauge`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/MetricBuilder.scala#L39) method:

```
def gauge[A](name: String, scope: String = null)(f: => A): Gauge[A] = {
  wrapDwGauge(metricNameFor(name, scope), new DropwizardGauge[A] { def getValue: A = f })
}
```

This method has two parameter lists. The second parameter list, `(f: => A)` has a call-by-name argument named `f` that is of type `A`. A new `DropwizardGauge` is created with `f` and passed to [`wrapDwGauge`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/MetricBuilder.scala#L54), which creates a new `Gauge` instance. So the following devilry...

```
metrics.gauge("random-number") {
  Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 1000)
}.value
```

...is basically calling the `gauge` method, passing it two arguments (the `String` `"random-number"` and the `Int` result of `Math.abs(new Random().nextInt() % 1000)`), then calling `.value` on the result. The `.value` returns an `Int`, because as we can see [here](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/Gauge.scala#L35), `.value` just calls the `getValue` method on the created `DropwizardGauge`.

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that RandomNumberGaugeExample inherits a metricsRegistry instance because it extends Instrumented. But I'm not seeing where that metrics instance is defined, what type it is, and how RandomNumberGaugeExample gets asscess to it. Wouldn't RandomNumberGaugeExample just have access to a metricsRegistry?!

The `metrics` instance is inherited from the [`InstrumentedBuilder`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/InstrumentedBuilder.scala#L75) trait, as shown in the source code.

```
trait InstrumentedBuilder extends BaseBuilder {
  protected lazy val metricBuilder = new MetricBuilder(metricBaseName, metricRegistry)

  /**
   * The MetricBuilder that can be used for creating timers, counters, etc.
   */
  def metrics: MetricBuilder = metricBuilder

  /**
   * The MetricRegistry where created metrics are registered.
   */
  val metricRegistry: MetricRegistry
}
```

> Also what is this devilry...

The [`Gauge`](https://github.com/erikvanoosten/metrics-scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/nl/grons/metrics/scala/Gauge.scala) object defines an `apply` method:

```
object Gauge {
  def apply[A](f: => A) = new Gauge[A](new DropwizardGauge[A] {
    def getValue: A = f
  })
}
```

This allows the returned `Gauge` object to be treated like a function that accepts one argument, which is itself a function that returns a value.

For further reference, I recommend these chapters in the [Scala tutorials](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/).

- [Traits](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/traits.html)
- [Higher-order functions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/higher-order-functions.html)